# How to specify a type that represents the arg types of a specific function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function (called **runLater** below) that takes two parameters:

1. an arbitrary function
2. an array of parameters for that
   arbitrary function

like this:

```
function runLater(aFunction, aFunctionsParams) {
    // store for later use
}
```

**How can I type the runLater function**, so that when I pass in a function as first parameter, the second parameter is restricted to the parameter types of that function?

```
function logNameAndAge(name: string, age: number) {...}

runLater(logNameAndAge, ['hoff', 42]) // ok, the parameter types match up
runLater(logNameAndAge, [false, 'oops']) // no ok, someFunction has [string, number] as paramters
```

Comment: Instead of passing a function and parameters, use a closure to pass a function with the parameters specified.   `runLater(() => logNameAndAge,('hoff', 42))`

Comment: typescript has a utility type called Parameters<TFunc>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### easy peasy with `Parameters<T>` [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html)!

```js
type func = (...args: any) => any

function runLater<T extends func>(aFunction: T, aFunctionsParams: Parameters<T>) {
    // store for later use
}

function logNameAndAge(name: string, age: number) {}

// ok:
runLater(logNameAndAge, ['hoff', 42])

// errors:
//   Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
//   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
runLater(logNameAndAge, [false, 'oops'])
```

Comment: @Hoff No problem! Have you seen any six-fingered men?